# Incorrect animation duration

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qtquick2

I noticed very weird behavior of animation with QML.
I have developped a test application to get into the animation features.
On my PC at the office, I have installed Qt 5.4 under Windows 7 64 Bits.

I am sure that the animations are "played" faster than the expected duration.
e.g.

```
// *** Image item for "Failure" event ***
    Image{
        id: failPanel
        x: 300
        y: -300
        source: "images/fail.png"
        scale: 0.5
        visible: false

        function startAnim() {
            visible = true
            x =  300
            y =  -300
            failAnim.restart()
        }

        SequentialAnimation {
            id: failAnim
            NumberAnimation{ target: failPanel; property: "y"; to:300; duration: 700; easing.type: Easing.InOutQuad}
            NumberAnimation{ target: failPanel; property: "y"; to:500; duration: 2000 }
            NumberAnimation{ target: failPanel; property: "x"; to:-1500; duration: 700; easing.type: Easing.InBack}
        }
    }
```

Everything is played much faster than the specified duration I didn't pay attention to it until I recompile the same source code at home with much faster PC (Windows 8 64 Bits).
On my personal PC, the animations is played at expected timing...

Very weird. 
Well, I wonder if anyone has already experienced this issue, or if there are particular QML settings related to this subject ?

Comment: Here are a couple ideas: (1) the scale is set to 0.5, maybe that is affecting how the animation appears to your brain, even though it takes the same amount of time, or (2) maybe try setting the duration to 5 seconds and timing it with a timer or clock/watch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can verify whether or not the timing is correct by using `JavaScript`'s `Date` object:

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Window 2.0

Window {
    id: root
    y: 30
    width: 1000
    height: 800
    visible: true

    Rectangle{
        id: failPanel
        x: 300
        y: -300
        color: "red"
        scale: 0.5
        width: 400
        height: 400
        visible: false

        property var startDate

        Component.onCompleted: startAnim()

        function startAnim() {
            visible = true
            x =  300
            y =  -300
            failAnim.restart()

            startDate = new Date()
            print("started animation at", startDate.toISOString())
        }

        SequentialAnimation {
            id: failAnim
            NumberAnimation{ target: failPanel; property: "y"; to:300; duration: 700; easing.type: Easing.InOutQuad}
            NumberAnimation{ target: failPanel; property: "y"; to:500; duration: 2000 }
            NumberAnimation{ target: failPanel; property: "x"; to:-1500; duration: 700; easing.type: Easing.InBack}

            onStopped: print("finished animation at", new Date().toISOString())
        }
    }
}
```

For me (Windows 10, Qt 5.6), it works:

```
qml: started animation at 2016-01-31T06:29:31.209Z
qml: finished animation at 2016-01-31T06:29:34.631Z
```

Your problem sounds similar to [this](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-43811) bug report. You might be able to find similar ones there, too.

I'd also recommend trying with a newer version of Qt, if possible.

Comment: I already measured the exec time on Friday. And it's indeed incorrect. However, thanks for the Qt bugreport you provided. It seems to be a major bug in Qt 5.4.1. It's also described here: https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-42699
Qt 5.4.1 seems to be affected and this the version I use at the office. There's a workaround by settings some env variable but I'll test with newer Qt version. At home, I'm using Qt 5.5 and it just works fine.

Answer (score 0):

We had similar issue in the company I work for.
The problem appeared to be that we hogged the main thread for a few milliseconds after starting the animation. If the main thread is working, the gui does not update since no update events are processed. When control finaly returns to the event loop, all update events are handled at once, causing the animation ro run faster.

Solution is to start the animation once your program runs idle. Easyest way to do this is probably to connect a slot to start the animation with a signal using a queued connection. Then the animation will start after controll is handed to the eventloop.